# Any way to recycle application in two servers at once programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

I have used this syntax to recycle my application.

```
    HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

You may ask why do I need to recycle my application, its to clear cache and this syntax is programmed to work only during an update performed in the application which is very infrequent.

So, my question is that, is there any way to actually recycle the other server as well through this syntax? 
Its a webfarm, so, only the cache from the current server gets cleared with the syntax above.

I have asked a similar question before:
[Is there any way to clear cache from server farm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816268/is-there-any-way-to-clear-cache-from-server-farm)

The reason I'm unable to apply the suggestion given in the previous question is because my organization disagreed to implement a third party tool.

Please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a third party provider to implement your own `OutputCacheProvider`, the links I provided in the answer to your previous question [Is there any way to clear cache from server farm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816268/is-there-any-way-to-clear-cache-from-server-farm) just suggested distributed cache because you were asking about having **one** cache for your web farm. If you are happy enough to have a per server cache and just want to invalidate an entry you can still implement your own cache provider and just have some way of invalidating the cache on all servers in the web farm.

Consider something like this:

```
Public Class MyOutputCacheProvider
Inherits OutputCacheProvider

Private Shared ReadOnly _cache As ObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default
Private ReadOnly _cacheDependencyFile As String = "\\networklocation\myfile.txt"
Private Shared _lastUpdated As DateTime

Public Sub New()
    'Get value for LastWriteTime
    _lastUpdated = File.GetLastWriteTime(_cacheDependencyFile)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function [Get](key As String) As Object

    'If file has been updated try to remove the item from cache and return null
    If _lastUpdated <> File.GetLastWriteTime(_cacheDependencyFile) Then
        Remove(key)
        Return Nothing
    End If

    'return item from cache
    Return _cache.Get(key)
End Function



Public Overrides Function Add(key As String, entry As Object, utcExpiry As DateTime) As Object
    'If the item is already in cache no need to add it
    If _cache.Contains(key) Then
        Return entry
    End If

    'add item to cache
    _cache.Add(New CacheItem(key, entry), New CacheItemPolicy() With {.AbsoluteExpiration = utcExpiry})
    Return entry
End Function


Public Overrides Sub [Set](key As String, entry As Object, utcExpiry As DateTime)
    'If key does not exist in the cache, value and key are used to insert as a new cache entry. 
    'If an item with a key that matches item exists, the cache entry is updated or overwritten by using value
    _cache.Set(key, entry, utcExpiry)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Remove(key As String)
    'if item exists in cache - remove it
    If _cache.Contains(key) Then
        _cache.Remove(key)
    End If
End Sub End Class
```

So basically you would be using a file on a network share or something to invalidate your cache. When you want to force the application to invalidate the cache you would just have to update the file somehow:

```
        'Take an action that will affect the write time.
    File.SetLastWriteTime(_cacheDependencyFile, Now)
```

I haven't tested this code now but I have previously implemented something similar and you can probably see what I'm getting at right?